# when install brightscript library in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, roku, brightscript

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: BrightScript Core 1.2.0.201903201715 (com.roku.brightscript.ide.eclipse.core.feature.group 1.2.0.201903201715)
  Missing requirement: BrightScript Core 1.2.0.201903201715 (com.roku.brightscript.ide.eclipse.core.feature.group 1.2.0.201903201715) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.dltk.core 5.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: It requires something from Eclipse DLTK (Dynamic Language ToolKit). Make you have 'contact all update sites during install to find required software' checked on the Install New Software page

Comment: @greg-449  this package already  installed

Comment: Then most likely it is the wrong version. The log is saying at least version 5.0.0 is required

Comment: how can i install it

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are trying to install with latest version of eclipse. Officially roku plugin supports eclipse neon, but you can install it with 2019-06(4.12.0) or prior versions of eclipse. And please make sure that you are using the eclipse for java developers. Hope this will help.